# 'this' on line8 is undefined, but on line 14,19,20 'this' works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, this

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  state = { term: "Search" };

  onFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui segment">
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="ui form">
          <div className="field">
            <label>Image Search</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ term: e.target.value })}
              onClick={(e) => this.setState({ term: "" })}
              value={this.state.term}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb62C.png)

TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
onFormSubmit
D:/Projects/pics/src/SearchBar.js:8
5 |
6 |  onFormSubmit(event) {
7 |    event.preventDefault();

> 8 |    console.log(this.state.term);
> | ^   9 |  }
> 10 |
> 11 |  render() {

Comment: Which line is which number?

Comment: Change `onFormSubmit` to also be an arrow function and it will retain the this context `onFormSubmit = (event) => {`

Comment: on lines 14,19,20 'this' is placed within arrow functions which see 'this' in their parents, but your submit function is not an arrow function so the 'this' keyword doesn't refer to component. in order to fix this, you can change the `onFormSubmit` function to arrow function.

Comment: <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="ui form"> there is no arrow function, but still 'this' works here

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about "this" in js.

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  state = { term: "Search" };

  onFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // console.log(this);
    console.log(event);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui segment">
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="ui form">
          <div className="field">
            <label>Image Search</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ term: e.target.value })}
              onClick={(e) => this.setState({ term: "" })}
              value={this.state.term}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```